# How to redirect to error page from onexception method instead of returning to jQuery/Ajax call in c# mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to redirect to an Error page inside onexception method when an exception occurs. But the thing is I have Ajax function, so even if I redirect inside onexception class, it does not redirect to error page and it always end up with executing Ajax function. Please can anyone suggest a solution for this.

This is my controller method and when exception throws, it will call to base controller on exception method.

```
 public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            try
            {

                string displayMessage = string.Empty;
                //Delete ward details and check successfulness of the function and return json result
                if (wardManager.DeleteWard(id) == true)
                {
                    displayMessage = CustomEnumMessage.GetStringValue(ConfirmationMessages.ConfirmationErrorMsg);
                    return Json(new { Message = displayMessage });
                }
                //Return json result if unsuccessfull 
                else
                {
                    displayMessage = CustomEnumMessage.GetStringValue(ConfirmationMessages.ConfirmationRemovedMsg);
                    return Json(new { Message = displayMessage });
                }

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

This is my base controller onexception method

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            //Get exception type
            System.Type ExceptionType = filterContext.Exception.GetType();


            if (ExceptionType.Name == "DbUpdateException")
            {
                ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = filterContext.Exception.InnerException.Message;
                this.View("DatabaseException", filterContext.Exception).ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);

            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["ErrorMessage"] = filterContext.Exception.Message;
                this.View("ApplicationException", filterContext.Exception).ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
            }

}
```

This is my Ajax function

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    jsonpCallback: "onJSONPLoad",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
                    data: $('#form').serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#submit').hide();
                        TriggerMsg(data.Message);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        if (xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').indexOf('application/json') > -1) {
                            var json = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                            alert(json.errorMessage);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

I built this Ajax function for only displaying Successful messages and it avoids me to redirecting to error page. The problem is even if i redirect to error page inside onexception method, finally fire into Ajax error: function and it does not redirect into DatabaseException or ApplicationException views. Can anyone suggest a solution for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I think that you need to check if the request is Ajax inside your `OnException` and return JSON object if so. Check out this article http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc, it may help you. You also have to mark the Exception as handled: `filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;`

Comment: Hi vortex.....Actually Ajax request is not in my OnException. Ajax request is in DeleteConfirmed(It is another controller) method and onException method belongs to an another controller.When exception occurs in DeleteConfirmed  method, First fire into onException methods then I need redirect to error page.

Comment: Why don't you try with `HandleError Attribute`? http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/19D9140313-Exception-or-Error-Handling-and-Logging-in-MVC4.html It`s explained how to handle ajax calls.

Comment: You can not preform a redirect on the server when using ajax. what you can do is ser the window.location.href = "ErrorPage" in the error: function (xhr). BUT you will only get the ajax error

Comment: Hi vortex.....Thanks your solution.....But the result is same.I tried also your method.When I used the Ajax function with HandleError Attribute,When exception happen,It does not redirect to Error page.My issue will not be solved with that.

Comment: Hi KevDevMan.....Thanks your solution.....As you have said,the thing is when I try to solve my problem inside error:function (xhr),It will show only ajax error.It does not show the actual error that happened in the server side....Can anyone suggest a real working solution for this.....it is a headache to me...:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you do a post from an ajax function, whatever result you have in your controller will always end up coming back to the success function.

What you want to do is return a url to your ajax function and from there redirect the user.

In your controller return the following

```
result = Json(new { redirect = Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "" }) });
```

Then in your javascript you will look for this redirect variable and set the window.location to it

```
success: function (data) {
     if (data.redirect) {
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        }           
    },
```

If you also want to pass a message then you can probably put it in the session such as `Session["ErrorMessage"] = error` from the controller and use it the same way in your error view